# Don't reopen files when starting Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like IDEA to start, each time, with all files closed (except for the README) and all folders collapsed. This is the default behavior when you open IDEA the first time after cloning a project.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable this behavior. The last open files and the state of the trees are stored in the binary format in IntelliJ IDEA [system directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) (caches).

IDE will not try to reopen the last files and restore the state of the trees for the project only if `.idea/workspace.xml` file is not present in the project.

Comment: I made the `.idea/workspace.xml` file readonly and disabled write access to the system, user, and admin accounts. Still any files I open are staying open the next time I open the IDE. I'm using maven and have checked the `AppData/Roaming/JetBrains` folder for extra configuration files but couldn't find any.

Comment: @TylerGrinn my answer was not complete, I've updated it with more details.